# mongoose save post hook vs updateOne post hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hook

I am trying to get access to the mongoose Document in a 'updateOne' post hook - I would like to get the document I've updated. I saw a difference in behavior between the 'save' post hook and the 'updateOne' post hook in mongoose. The 'save' post hook gives access to the document:

```
postSchema.post('save', async function (doc) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc._id);
});
```

gives the document, and the document id correctly. On the other hand:

```
postSchema.post('updateOne', async function (doc) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc._id);
});
```

does not have any of the document's properties, the doc prints: `{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`.
Is there a way to get access to the doc we modified in 'updateOne' just like we do for 'save'? Or, is there another query I could use for this purpose? Thank you!

Comment: You could try with `findOneAndUpdate` ''https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate

Comment: updateOne doesn't return the updated document, so use Model.findOneAndUpdate or Model.findOneAndUpdate  with `{new: true}` option, and use `findOneAndUpdate` post hook to get accces to the document.